# Display Last Saved Date on worksheet

Tags: excel

Does anyone know how to display the Last Saved Date of an Excel Spreadsheet on one of the worksheets?

I have found ways to do it using macros, but the spreadsheet is populated by an add-in called Jet Essentials, and this does not like macros so a solution here must not use one.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

thought I would update on this.

Found out that adding to the VB Module behind the spreadsheet does not actually register as a Macro.

So here is the solution:

1. Press ALT + F11
2. Click Insert > Module
3. Paste the following into the window:

Code

```
Function LastSavedTimeStamp() As Date
  LastSavedTimeStamp = ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")
End Function
```

4. Save the module, close the editor and return to the worksheet.
5. Click in the Cell where the date is to be displayed and enter the following formula:

Code

```
=LastSavedTimeStamp()
```

Comment: `... = ThisWorkbook.Bui ...` might prevent problems.

Comment: When I tried this in Excel 2010 - it **did** consider that addition a macro and required saving it as a macro-enabled spreadsheet.

Comment: In case you’re new to Excel, be advised to complete the above you may:
1. Need to save your file as an “Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm) – Can use File/Save As
2. Need to format the cell where you put the “=LastSavedTimeStamp()” command.  If so, right-click on that cell and select “Format Cells…”; click the “Number” tab and select “Date”; then under “Type” select how you want it formatted.  Click “OK.”
Above directions were written using Excel 2010.

Comment: I was prompted to save the workbook as a macro-enabled workbook but I ignored this, selecting to save as a normal workbook and it seems to work as expected.  I am using Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010, Version 14.0.7188.5002 (32-bit).

Answer (score 2):

This might be an alternative solution. Paste the following code into the new module:

```
Public Function ModDate()
ModDate = 
Format(FileDateTime(ThisWorkbook.FullName), "m/d/yy h:n ampm") 
End Function
```

Before saving your module, make sure to save your Excel file as Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook.

Paste the following code into the cell where you want to display the last modification time:

```
=ModDate()
```

I'd also like to recommend an alternative to Excel allowing you to add creation and last modification time easily. Feel free to check on RowShare and this article I wrote: https://www.rowshare.com/blog/en/2018/01/10/Displaying-Last-Modification-Time-in-Excel

Answer (score 1):

May be this time stamp fit you better
Code

```
Function LastInputTimeStamp() As Date
  LastInputTimeStamp = Now()
End Function
```

and each time you input data in defined cell (in my example below it is cell C36) you'll get a new constant time stamp.
As an example in Excel file may use this

```
=IF(C36>0,LastInputTimeStamp(),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simple add the following into the Header or Footer of the Worksheet

Last Saved: &[Date] &[Time]

Answer (score -1):

There is no built in function with this capability. The close would be to save the file in a folder named for the current date and use the =INFO("directory") function.

Comment: =INFO("DIRECTORY") only shows the file path, not the file name?

Comment: Sorry, save it in a folder named for the date.

Comment: Hmm, not really a viable solution as the file is accessed by a number of users and is regularly updated. Thanks anyway

Comment: I don't follow. Why would multiple users affect this?

Comment: Its a bit awkward to locate a file if its containing folder is constantly changing

Comment: You can't put the new folders in another folder which doesn't change?