# Execute Formula with VBA Function Upon Saving

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have the below VBA code to return the last saved time stamp in a cell.

The formula only works when I enter the formula bar and click enter. I want the formula to automatically update upon saving.

```
Function LastSavedTimeStamp() As Date
    LastSavedTimeStamp = ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")
End Function
```

Comment: Make the UDF Volatile.  Add `Application.Volatile` as the first line in the function.

Comment: @ScottCraner - I did try that and doesn't seem to work here.

Comment: OP - best to use `ThisWorkbook` to refer to the workbook the code is in. That's also mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489418/display-last-saved-date-on-worksheet#comment50040869_26606883) in the original question.

Comment: @BigBen it does not work on save but as soon as any thing else changes it will adjust.

Comment: @ScottCraner - yeah that's a good point. I think `AfterSave` event might get us the full way there.

Comment: @BigBen Yes, Put `Application.Calculate` also in a `Workbook_AfterSave` event in ThisWorkbook and it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the UDF Volatile:

```
Function LastSavedTimeStamp() As Date
  Application.Volatile
  LastSavedTimeStamp = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")
End Function
```

Then in the `ThisWorkbook` Module add:

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    Application.Calculate
End Sub
```